# How often does Careers update my profile?

Tags: support, jobs

I wanted to know how often Careers updates stuff like reputation, activity, etc.

Since my careers profile says I've been inactive for five days but hardly a day goes by when I don't post a question or an answer.

links:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/bevacqua
https://stackoverflow.com/users/389745/nico

Comment: Someone probably just needs to wake up the hamster.

Comment: @Lasse:  Damn lazy hamsters don't know how good they have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that Nico, everything should be back in order now.